# PHP - Compare exploded word with mysql varchar in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can I compare exploded word with mysql varchar in PHP?
This code produce what i want but it also give this error

veranderenwachtwoordjij
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object......

```
$word = "Also, to be safe, change your password regularly... you don't have to be obsessive about it: every three hours or so should be enough. And because erring on the side of caution is always a good idea, fake your own suicide and change your identity at least once a year.";

$pieces = explode(" ", $word);

$x = 0;
while($x < word_count($word)) {  // word count function returns int (51)
  $aPiece = $pieces[$x]; // change $pieces[$x] to 'you' and then it works
  $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM dict WHERE english='$aPiece'");

  $z = 0;
  while($z < $num_result) // $num_result returns amount of rows in database
  {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); //error line is here
    echo stripslashes($row['dutch']);
    $z++;
  }

  $x++;
}
```

Comment: It has been a long time since I did any PHP. Did they deprecate the `for`-loop?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem comes from the `don't` in your test sentence : you forgot to escape quotes  with a function like `mysql_real_escape_string`.

For example :

```
$aPiece = mysql_real_escape_string($pieces[$x]);
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM dict WHERE english='$aPiece'");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

`$row = $result2->fetch_assoc();`

should be

`$row = $result->fetch_assoc();`

since you don't seem to have a $result anywhere.

Comment: oops..it's a typo
should be $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

Answer (score 0):

$result2 in $result2->fetch_assoc(); is not the correct variable, it should be

```
$result->fetch_assoc();
```

by the way you have to delete the punctuation marks in order to find the words in your database (I think) one of your first lines should (before the explode) be similar to this:

```
$words = strtr($words, ',.:!','');
```